# Import class from a different gradle module

Tags: java, scala, intellij-idea, gradle

I have a project consisting of of two gradle projects defined as following in the build.gradle file.

```
project(':clients') {
  archivesBaseName = "clients"

  dependencies {  
    compile libs.lz4
    compile libs.snappy
    compile libs.slf4jApi

    testRuntime libs.slf4jlog4j
  }

  jar {
    dependsOn createVersionFile
    from("$buildDir") {
        include "proj/$buildVersionFileName"
    }
  }

}
```

and

```
project(':core') {
  apply plugin: 'scala'
  apply plugin: "org.scoverage"
  archivesBaseName = "proj_${versions.baseScala}"

  dependencies {
    compile project(':clients')
    compile libs.joptSimple
    compile libs.metrics
    compile libs.scala
    compile libs.slf4jlog4j
    compile libs.zkclient
    compile libs.zookeeper
    compile libs.scalaParserCombinators

  }

  tasks.create(name: "copyDependantLibs", type: Copy) {
    from (configurations.testRuntime) {
      include('slf4j-log4j12*')
    }
    from (configurations.runtime) {
      exclude('kafka-clients*')
    }
    into "$buildDir/dependant-libs-${versions.scala}"
    duplicatesStrategy 'exclude'
  }

  jar {
    dependsOn('copyDependantLibs')
  }

  tasks.create(name: "copyDependantTestLibs", type: Copy) {
    from (configurations.testRuntime) {
      include('*.jar')
    }
    into "$buildDir/dependant-testlibs"
    duplicatesStrategy 'exclude'
  }

  systemTestLibs.dependsOn('jar', 'testJar', 'copyDependantTestLibs')

}
```

The issue is that I can NOT import any class defined inside the 'core' module from inside the 'clients' module. However, the other way round works fine.
That is probably because we mention `compile project(':clients')` as a dependency for the 'core' module. When I put `compile project(':core')` as a dependency for the 'clients' module, IntelliJ allows me to import the classes from 'core' module into 'clients'. However, gradle then rightfully claims that there is a cyclic build dependency between these two modules.

To sum it up, how to make classes in 'core' accessible inside 'clients' without putting them as compile dependencies of each other.

Comment: Do you have `settings.gradle` file defined? Basically it should _just work_.

Comment: Make `clients` a sub project of `core`.

Comment: @Opal I do have a `settings.gradle` file but it just says `include 'core', 'clients'`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> we mention `compile project(':clients')` as a dependency for the `'core'` module

Why do you need this? If you do, then you can't use classes from `core` in `clients`, because to compile them you need to compile `clients` first, but to compile `clients` you need classes from `core`, etc.

If you need only some specific classes from `clients` in `core`, you can move them into a third module which both `client` and `core` depend on. Or do the same with the classes from `core` which you need in `clients`.

If you have a cyclic dependency between specific classes (e.g. class `A` from `core` needs to import `B` from `clients`, which needs to import `A` again; the loop may include more than 2 classes), then they must be in a single module.

Comment: So are you saying that there is no way to address this issue without changing the project structure?

Comment: No, there is not (unless I misunderstood what you need). Another thing which might help depending on your exact requirements is not to refer to classes from `core` in `clients` directly, but to define interfaces in `clients` and make `core` classes implement these interfaces.